# How to read *.g file format

Tags: r, dataframe, geometry, k-means, data-mining

I have a large weather data files for each year for state of TX. The files are in .g format and they contain 4 dimension. I am trying everything I can find but still were not successful to read these .g files in R. I need to read them and separate specific month from the year and run K-means clustering on them.

Comment: you need to give us more information, please.  Can you point to any kind of online reference that describes the way these files are structured?

Comment: ...or even open the file up in a text editor and show us what it looks like?